# JavaMail base64 encoding

Tags: java, encoding, base64, jakarta-mail, mime

I have some Java code which sends out an email with code somewhat like the following:

```
MimeBodyPart part = new MimeBodyPart();
part.setContent(htmlString, "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
part.setHeader("MIME-Version", "1.0");
part.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
part.setHeader("Importance", severityVal);

mimeMultiPart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
mimeMessage.setContent(mimeMultiPart);
```

... and so on.

How can I encode the "part" MimeBodyPart in base64 for this outgoing email?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html):

Q: Even though JavaMail does all the encoding and decoding for me, I need to manually control the encoding for some body parts. 
A: In the rare case that you need to control the encoding, there are several ways to override JavaMail's default behavior. A simple approach is as follows. After creating the entire message, call `msg.saveChanges()` and then use something like `mbp.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64")` to force base64 encoding for the given body part.

Another approach is to subclass `MimeBodyPart` and override the `updateHeaders` method so that it first calls `super.updateHeaders()` and then sets the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header as above.

Comment: I have similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59166613/811293 please tell me about this.

Answer (score 3):

simply add this statement:

```
part.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
```

**after** the lines of code that set `part.setDataHandler(..)` or `part.setContent(...)`, and the dataSource/Handler will adapt itself to match the content transfer encoding you just specified for the body part.

You may also want to consider setting the headers by the same token, e.g.:

```
part.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
```