# javax.mail.Authenticator with base 64 Encoding

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a server which requires ID und Password has to be encoded in Base64. Meaning instead of `Username` you have to encode it into Base64 first and give the encoded String in.

And then in my Java Client i have an `javax.mail.Authenticator`. I manually encoded ID and Password into base64, save them to strings and initialize the Authenticator with those Strings. But then the ID and password is wrong, even if i checked again and again.

What could be wrong in this case ?

Edit : The other question was about body part, here it is about `Authenticator`

Comment: you manual encoding could be wrong, the way you set them to the authenticator, ... hard to tell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaMail base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9124554/javamail-base64-encoding)

Comment: @AxelH I encoded with the help of a Website, and log in with those results, it worked, but not for my Java Client..

Comment: @AxelH Anyway I read the other question already, i dont want to encode my MimeBodyPart yet because my authentication is even working..

Comment: What authentication mechanism is the server using?  If it's using one of the standard ones that requires base64 encoding, JavaMail will do that encoding for you.  Have you tried it without encoding them?  If it's using one of the mechanisms that normally requires a plain text username and password, but it wants you to base64 encode them first, then you'll have to do that yourself.  And note that you usually [don't need an Authenticator](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), just use the connect or send method that allows you to specify the username and password.

Comment: Hi @BillShannon please see my answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for my Question is that openssl in mailserver requires Base64 Encoding, While when i connect through a java Client, its UTF-8.

Comment: That is, JavaMail does any required base64 encoding for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use java.util.Base64. Encoding and decoding would go as:

```
String s = "...full Unicode...";
s = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
s = new String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(s), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

There are some tweaks possible, like no padding at the end, alternative URL safe Base64 and such.